# How to exit Tig search view?

Tags: search, terminal, tig

In Tig, press the `</>` key to enter the search view. But if I accidentally press it, how should I quit?

I tried the <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to no avail.

I made a [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiu2e.jpg) about it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiu2e.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit the search prompt

Comment: It's totally available. Thank you. 

Answer (score 0):

You can also hit `enter` to just run the search (doesn't matter if it's an invalid one). You'll just receive a `No match found for "your search"` message while recovering the focus on your view

Comment: I tested it, and in the search view, when I don't enter anything and just click the `Enter`, it matches the 'q' character!

Comment: That doesn't happen to me. And what if you hit `backspace` to erase any weird character (so nothing gets matched)?

Comment: Under the search view, whether you click the `backspace` button or not, the results are all the same. For more information, please see [here](https://imgur.com/McrY5J5).

https://imgur.com/McrY5J5

Comment: I tested it, and in the search view, without entering anything, it will search for the last character entered.